# What is the name of "grass" used to garnish a bento (takeout meal)?

Tags: culture, word-requests

I have a piece of "grass paper"? included in my meal, want to know it's purpose. It isn't edible, and could be a choking hazard. I also don't know what it is called.

Comment: Maybe including a picture of it would help get faster and more accurate replies.

Comment: It is a green piece of plastic/paper with jagged edges on one side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the bento grass is called "haran" and is a plastic substitute for leaves and grasses that were originally used to enclose sushi and vegetables to preserve the flavor and taste of the item wrapped, and to reduce spoilage. The item is also used to add color and overall appeal to the meal when displayed.

Additional information can be reviewed at:

http://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2008/01/15/reference/bento-grass/#.WI4HQflEnIU

Comment: barely more than a link to an external site - Could you quote something from the site, please?http://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers